# How to downgrade dnsmasq?

Tags: ubuntu, dnsmasq

after upgrating to ubuntu 11.04, I lost dnsmasq.

When I run `/usr/sbin/dnsmasq start` I get

```
dnsmasq: junk found in command line
```

Apparently I need to downgrade dnsmasq but Package->Force version is not available for it in synaptic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to remove it and install from source version you need.

Answer (score 2):

It's not apparent that you need to downgrade dnsmasq. `start` is not one of the options for dnsmasq. You can verify this by viewing the dnsmasq options with `man dnsmasq`. Where you trying to start dnsmasq? If so, run `service dnsmasq start` as root.

Answer (score 1):

Don't downgrade.
If you have package dns-root-data installed and are able to remove this then this will "fix" the dnsmasq problem.

Elsewhere, I have seen it mentioned that this is due to systemd adding rubbish into the dnsmasq configuration - this may not be actually true!

A reboot **may** be necessary.

Comment: Probably with the `dns-root-data` using a different format than what `dnsmasq`'s init script expects